# Loading PartialView into Bootstrap modal while passing ID value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load  PartialView inside a Bootstrap modal. Right now I am generating the URL in code as I am displaying data in a datatable and the best approach I've found to generate a link is through code. Right now the modal and everything is firing up, but I don't see the partial view anywhere. I am suppose to pass an ID to this partial view so it loads some specific data. Here's my URL in C#:

```
 dto.URL = String.Format("<a href=\"#myModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\" 
 id=\"{0}\" data-target=\"#edit-modal\">View Details</a>", item.Id);
```

Which translates to :

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="20" data-target="#edit-modal">Select</a>
```

Here's my modal window:

```
<div id="edit-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript to load this partial view:

```
    $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

        var $modal = $(this),
            listId = e.relatedTarget.id;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/list/_getService/' + listId,
            success: function (data) {
                $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

I never see the Partial View firing up, nor even the script is being hit when using Chrome's JS Debugger. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs assistance I fixed it like this:

```
    $(function () { 
        $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var id = e.relatedTarget.id;
            var $modal = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/list/_getService/' + id,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
                        }
                    });
        });
    });
```